# Specifying sources overrides synctoken using Google Script and People API

Tags: google-apps-script, google-people-api

I'm running this code using Google's "Try It" at https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people.connections/list.

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"></script>
<script>
  /**
   * Sample JavaScript code for people.people.connections.list
   * See instructions for running APIs Explorer code samples locally:
   * https://developers.google.com/explorer-help/guides/code_samples#javascript
   */

  function authenticate() {
    return gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance()
        .signIn({scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly"})
        .then(function() { console.log("Sign-in successful"); },
              function(err) { console.error("Error signing in", err); });
  }
  function loadClient() {
    return gapi.client.load("https://people.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v1")
        .then(function() { console.log("GAPI client loaded for API"); },
              function(err) { console.error("Error loading GAPI client for API", err); });
  }
  // Make sure the client is loaded and sign-in is complete before calling this method.
  function execute() {
    return gapi.client.people.people.connections.list({
      "resourceName": "people/me",
      "personFields": "names",
      "sources": [
        "READ_SOURCE_TYPE_CONTACT"
      ],
      "syncToken": "MisAPB3nNAAAABIIsK7pgqKn8gIQsK7pgqKn8gI4IFedl0ChD-QAdeetUtBPOgw2ODIzOTA3NzkxNzA="
    })
        .then(function(response) {
                // Handle the results here (response.result has the parsed body).
                console.log("Response", response);
              },
              function(err) { console.error("Execute error", err); });
  }
  gapi.load("client:auth2", function() {
    gapi.auth2.init({client_id: "YOUR_CLIENT_ID"});
  });
</script>
<button onclick="authenticate().then(loadClient)">authorize and load</button>
<button onclick="execute()">execute</button>
```

When I exclude

```
"sources": ["READ_SOURCE_TYPE_CONTACT"]
```

from the "execute" function, the code returns only the contacts changed since the last sync token was set (my desired outcome).  However, when I include that line, *all* of my contacts are returned.  Anyone have any idea why this is happening and how to avoid it (other than removing the line - I need to exclude DOMAIN and PROFILE sources)?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people.connections/list):

1. > sources[]

   > Optional. A mask of what source types to return. Defaults to READ_SOURCE_TYPE_CONTACT and READ_SOURCE_TYPE_PROFILE if not set.
2. `When the pageToken or syncToken is specified, all other request parameters must match the first call.`.

In other words, in general it should not make a difference either you set `"sources": ["READ_SOURCE_TYPE_CONTACT"]` or not - since `sources` automatically defaults to `READ_SOURCE_TYPE_CONTACT`.

The most likely reason for why the API is not returning you the only new contacts correctly is that you changed the request by excluding the line `"sources": ["READ_SOURCE_TYPE_CONTACT"]` (and maybe you also changed something else?).

Comment: Yep, that was it.  I thought I had ensured that everything was the same, but when I went back through, I found that the person fields in my sync token update function was missing a parameter.  I put all of my person fields into a global array and used that every time it is referenced to ensure consistency.  Thanks!